# User Input Not Being Read Correctly in NodeJS CLI App

Tags: node.js, command-line, command-line-interface

I am trying to gather user input from the command line to create a simple command line interface application. I'm using the `standard_input.on()` function to be able to capture the user input and use it to determine what response the user should see in their command line. The data being captured is not being read properly in the callback function. Below is the code.

```
const fs = require("fs"),
path = require("path");

const dir = path.resolve(__dirname);

var standard_input = process.stdin;

standard_input.setEncoding('utf-8');

console.log("Please type yes or no.");

standard_input.on('data', function (data) {
   if(data === 'yes'){
      console.log("OK I will.");
      process.exit();
   } else if (data === 'no') {
      console.log("OK I won't.");
      process.exit();
   } else {
      console.log("Please enter yes or no.");
   }
});
```

The first prompt `"Please type yes or no."` executes correctly and I'm able to type in the command line, but when I type `yes` or `no` it responds with the `else` prompt: `Please enter yes or no.`

I have tried `yes`, `YES`, `'yes'`, and `'YES'`, as well as the same four formats for `no`. I also tried changing the line `if(data === 'yes')` to all four formats as well as `if(data === 'yes\n')` in case the enter was throwing the condition off.

Also when I `console.log(data)` it logs the correct data. So if I type `yes` the callback function will log `yes`. It seems to be working correctly aside from the actual `if/else` evaluation, it only hits the last `else` statement.

I am currently running on v8.11.1 of Node.

Comment: Note that the string will *include* the enter keypress as a newline `\n`.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I tried `if(data === 'yes\n')` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Try the other way - `data.trim() === "yes"` seems to work for me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out in the comments, using `data.trim()` on `data` before comparing it to `'yes'` and `'no'` resolved the issue.

Below is the corrected `if/else` statement.

```
if(data.trim() === 'yes'){
  console.log("OK I will.");
  process.exit();
} else if (data.trim() === 'no') {
  console.log("OK I won't.");
  process.exit();
} else {
  console.log("Please enter yes or no.");
}
```